# Confusing about Jquery Timer

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer

iam using jquery timer http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/ to create document in every 5 second and with pause and resume controlled button. here is my script :

```
$(function() { 
            $('.handler').load("../Pages/csFetchCustomer.ashx?");
            $('.controlled-interval').everyTime(5000, 'controlled', function() {
                $('.handler').load("../Pages/csFetchCustomer.ashx?");
                $('.stop').click(function() {
                    $('.controlled-interval').stopTime('controlled');
                });
            });
        });
```

with this script, i am already create document that load every 5 second with pause button controll,.
but how to create resume / play button control ?
any suggestion are welcome
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a working demo on their site that is doing what you want, but here's simplified code of mine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var active = true,
        runLoadEvery = function() {
            $('.controlled-interval').everyTime(5000, 'controlled', function() {
                $('.handler').load("../Pages/csFetchCustomer.ashx?");                    
            });
        };
    // start running as soon as ready event is fired
    runLoadEvery();

    $('.start').click(function() {
        active = true;
        runLoadEvery();
    });
    $('.stop').click(function() {
        active = false;
        $('.controlled-interval').stopTime('controlled');
    });
});
```

Comment: Working Flawlessly.. Thanks a lot WTK. Your script is really easy to understand.

Comment: Just curious, how to run runLoadEvery(); function in document ready event ? or maybe any docs that tell about it ? anyway thanks.